# Which of the following are bijections?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

• $f : \mathbb{Z} → \mathbb{Z} \\
f(x) = x^5 - 3$

• $g : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R} \\
g(x) = x^5 - 3$

• $h : \mathbb{Q} → \mathbb{Q} \\
h(x) = x^5 - 3$

• $F : \mathbb{R} → [0, ∞) \\
F(x) = e^x$

---

I'm so angry because when I look at the function $y = x^5 - 3 $on a graph it looks like it is not injective as the values in between, 1 and 0.000001(etc) looks like a straight line!) I want to say that from $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ the function is bijective but some $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ it is not because it includes all those small values. Am I wrong?

Comment: How did you draw the graph?

Comment: Hint: $f(1) = -2, f(2) = 29$ Is $f$ surjective?

Comment: So for Z->Z it is not surjective therefore it is not bijective. I want to say the same thing for Q->Q. However for R->R all values are hit so it is bijective for R->R.

Comment: I merely input it into a graphing program! (i.e. Google)

Comment: Just for fun: If you think $x^5$ looks flat near 0, check out what $e^{-1/x^2}$ looks like near 0. I remember graphing that function in my undergrad days and being astonished by how flat it looks!

Comment: This is the **big** problem with drawing graphs on a computer - it completely kills off any understanding of what the graph really looks like.  (OK, not always - but sometimes it does.)  If you are able to draw the graph without computer assistance I think you will find your problem much easier.

Comment: @Rickon $h$ isn't surjective. could $0$ be in the image of $h$?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the graph of a function is not foolproof - if you look at the wrong scale, many features will be obscured.

Also, if you're dealing with functions defined on $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$, and graphing the function in $\mathbb{R}^2$, you'd need some precise way of seeing which points on the graph are in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ or $\mathbb{Q}^2$. Do you see why this is problematic? $1$ and $1.0000001$ are very very close...

Instead, think algebraically: Ask yourself, for example, "Are there two different real numbers $r$ and $s$ such that $g(r) = g(s)$? i.e. $r^5-3 = s^5-3$?"

And "Given an integer $a$, can I always find some *integer* $b$ such that $f(b) = a$? i.e. $b^5-3 = a$?"